# How to play musical notes in a DAW

Tags: guitar, piano, chords, acoustic-guitar, string-instruments

I play Acoustic Guitar & Harmonica as well. Recently, I have started using DAWs for composing my own tunes. Fruity Loop & Magix Music Maker are the two DAWs I use. These DAWs have built-in Piano Roll, using which we can compose tunes. I know how to play a C-Major, G-Major or any other code in a real acoustic guitar & harmonica. I want to play these notes in the DAW. All I see in front of me is a keyboard. I hope for some help.

Thanks.

Comment: There are some great tutorials on youtube and online about how to use the piano roll: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XTaRvjkvpSg

Comment: http://www.wikihow.com/Learn-Keyboard-Notes the notes on a Richter tuned C major harmonica correspond to the white keys.

Answer (score 2):

your question is very verbose , but I think you need a chord dictionary. you can use [this](http://keychord.com/) one.

Answer (score 2):

Depending which version of Fruity Loops you are using, there may be no need to look up the chords yourself. Here is [a nice tutorial](http://music.tutsplus.com/tutorials/introducing-the-fl-studio-basix-chord-tool--audio-8178) on how to use the chord tool that is built right in to FL Studio.

If you are only seeing piano keys instead of the letter names of the notes, try hitting the M key while you are in the Piano Roll view and it should switch.